# VB.net Download HTML of a URL

Tags: html, vb.net, internet-explorer, download, filestream

Im in need of downloading the HTML generated by a server after sending a URL. I thought maybe the webclient.downloadfile would work but it seems like it gives up when you don't end the URL with a file extension.

If I do have a webbrowser control set up that has navigated to a site on the same domain;however, that webbrowser has a handler set up for the documentcompleted event that I do not want to fire.

If the best solution is to load the page and use the webbrowser.documentstream to get a stream and write it to a file I have 2 questions:

1) the document.stream returns a system.io.stream and the file object uses system.io.filestream. Can I easily write a stream to a filestream and if so, how?

2) I answered this question for myself when I was typing it out :P

If this is not the best solution and the webclient can infact download a file after it's generated, how would I go about that?\

Edit: If I'm way off base, don't hesitate to let me know :) I'm still quite new to VB

edit:
The below is not working. My step through revealed that I am in fact passing usable data to the functions, but for some reason the files are still not being created.

Uniencoding declaration:

```
 Dim uniencoding As New System.Text.UnicodeEncoding()
```

Code:

```
 request = WebRequest.Create(tempstring)
    Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Dim html As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
            fstream = New FileStream(surl, FileMode.Create)
            fstream.Write(uniencoding.GetBytes(html), 0, Len(uniencoding.GetBytes(html))) 'Write the HTML to a local file
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: You don't need a file extension, this works great wc.DownloadFile("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181470/vb-net-download-html-of-a-url", "C:\temp.txt")  if you don't want to save to a file, you can use DownloadString

Comment: I do want to save to a file but downloadfile didn't seem to work. I'll post code in a second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is get the HTML (or whatever the response contains), without actually rendering it to the screen, you can do that easily using the [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class.

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com")
using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Using reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim html As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        File.WriteAllText("test.html", html)
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: This should work perfectly as I can simply write html as a string to a text file. I don't care about retaining white space and indentations :P

Comment: I edited Above to show what I'm trying to do. For some reason, the file is not getting created in the directory but the program is not returning errors. Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer to show a simple way of writing the html string out to a file.

Comment: Does this write files if they don't exist? if not, ill have to add a line for that.

Comment: I added to code create a file and I noticed 2 problems. I can't open the text file while the program is running meaning I have to close the stream ( no problem ) but the line didn't write to the file even when I manually added a valid HTML address...

Comment: The `File.WriteAllText` method will create the file if it does not exist and it will overwrite the file if it already exists.  It obviously doesn't give you as much control as some of the other file I/O options, but when that's all you need to do, it's quite simple and handy.

Comment: I'm not sure why your code using the `FileStream` is failing.  For me in cause an invalid cast exception, so I had to change `Len(uniencoding.GetBytes(html))` to `uniencoding.GetBytes(html).Length`, and I put it in a `Using` block so it would automatically close the file and dispose the stream.  But other than that it worked fine.  For what it's worth, if you do want to write a string to a stream, I would recommend using the `StreamWriter` to do it rather than getting the bytes from the encoding yourself.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer because theres gotta be something that I'm doing wrong. I'll figure it out, thanks for the push :)

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon this in the future: The issue as far as I can tell was that the site required authentication. Even though I had a browser that was authenticated, the webrequest and webclient weren't being able to use the authentication token. I regretably solved the issue by added a second webbrowser to the form and used the second one navigate, read the text and write to a file.