# FPL Player List download in VB.net

Tags: html, vb.net

I use the page https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list to get the total points of all players in FPL.  I can go to this page in a browser, right click and choose Save to save the contents as an HTML file.  Is there a way to do this in VB.NET?
I've tried

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list", "C:\FPL\fpl.txt")
```

But I get the following error:

> System.Net.WebException: 'The request was aborted: Could not create
> SSL/TLS secure channel.'

Thanks in advance. I was hoping to download an HTML file.

Comment: Have you tried the accepted answer on this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181470/vb-net-download-html-of-a-url